# Normalize dataframe series by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe like this

```
id    name    month    count
111   a       1        5
112   b       1        4
113   c       1        6
111   a       2        1
112   b       2        7
113   c       2        6
```

I want to normalize the values for a, b and c respectively.

The best approach is likely to groupby and aggregate, something like this:

```
df_normalized = df.groupby(["id", "name"]).agg(normalized_count=("count", "lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())")).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This however results in an AttributeError.

`AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())'`

Here is a similar way by using transform, which unfortunately doesn't seem to respect the "a,b,c".

[Normalize DataFrame by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046208/normalize-dataframe-by-group)

Another way, in the same thread, is rather ugly, and uses multiple steps:

```
means_stds = df.groupby('indx')['a0'].agg(['mean','std']).reset_index()
df = df.merge(means_stds,on='indx')
df['a0_normalized'] = (df['a0'] - df['mean']) / df['std']
```

Is there a way to achieve this using groupby?

Comment: The one in the answer below works like a charme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function:

```
df['c1_normalized'] = (df.groupby(["id", "name"])['count']
                         .transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()))
```

For compare is changed your second solution:

```
means_stds = df.groupby(["id", "name"])['count'].agg(['mean','std']).reset_index()
df = df.merge(means_stds,on=["id", "name"])
df['c2_normalized'] = (df['count'] - df['mean']) / df['std']
print (df)
    id name  month  count  c1_normalized  mean       std  c2_normalized
0  111    a      1      5       0.707107   3.0  2.828427       0.707107
1  111    a      2      1      -0.707107   3.0  2.828427      -0.707107
2  112    b      1      4      -0.707107   5.5  2.121320      -0.707107
3  112    b      2      7       0.707107   5.5  2.121320       0.707107
4  113    c      1      6            NaN   6.0  0.000000            NaN
5  113    c      2      6            NaN   6.0  0.000000            NaN
```

Comment: Ah thank you, adding the transform column didn't come to my mind. Very elegant