# How to use sklearn StandardScaler with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to normalize a pandas dataframe while grouping it based on the dates.

My dataset looks like this:

| date | permno | ret | cumret | mom1m | mom3m | mom6m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2004-01-30 | 80000 | 0.053 | 1.497 | 0.067 | 0.140 | 0.137 |
| 2004-02-29 | 80000 | 0.053 | 1.497 | 0.067 | 0.140 | 0.137 |
| 2004-03-31 | 80000 | 0.053 | 1.497 | 0.067 | 0.140 | 0.137 |
| 2004-01-30 | 80001 | 0.053 | 1.497 | 0.067 | 0.140 | 0.137 |
| 2004-02-29 | 80001 | 0.053 | 1.497 | 0.067 | 0.140 | 0.137 |
| 2004-03-31 | 80001 | 0.053 | 1.497 | 0.067 | 0.140 | 0.137 |

I'm trying to scale `mom1m`, `mom3m`, `mom6m` based on the dates.

So the first row should be scaled with the 4th row, the second row should be scaled with the 5th row, the third row should be scaled with the last row.

What I've tried is

```
crsp2[scale_cols] = crsp2.groupby('date')[scale_cols].apply(lambda x: StandardScaler().fit_transform(x))
```

where `crsp2` is the dataframe i'm trying to scale and `scale_cols` is the list of features I'm trying to scale.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046208/normalize-dataframe-by-group), you can do what you want with the below example code.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,9,11],
    'value2':[2,3,3,2,10,8,11,10]
})
df[['value', 'value2']] = df.groupby('group').transform(lambda x: StandardScaler().fit_transform(x.values[:,np.newaxis]).ravel())
```

| group | value | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1.34164 | -1 |
| 1 | -0.447214 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.447214 | 1 |
| 1 | 1.34164 | -1 |
| 2 | -1.15311 | 0.229416 |
| 2 | -0.733799 | -1.60591 |
| 2 | 0.524142 | 1.14708 |
| 2 | 1.36277 | 0.229416 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object here is other thread you may want.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution could use [`scale()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html) the pipelined version of the [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler).

Your code would look like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

# set permno and date as multi-index
crsp2.set_index(keys =["date", "permno"],drop=True)

# columns to scale
scale_cols = ["mom1m","mom3m", "mom6m"]

# apply scaler rankwise
crsp2[scale_cols] = crsp2.groupby('date')[scale_cols].transform(lambda x: scale(x))
```

**Output:**

```
date    permno  ret cumret  mom1m   mom3m   mom6m
0   2004-01-30  80000   0.053   1.497   0.0 0.0 0.0
1   2004-02-29  80000   0.053   1.497   0.0 0.0 0.0
2   2004-03-31  80000   0.053   1.497   0.0 0.0 0.0
3   2004-01-30  80001   0.053   1.497   0.0 0.0 0.0
4   2004-02-29  80001   0.053   1.497   0.0 0.0 0.0
5   2004-03-31  80001   0.053   1.497   0.0 0.0 0.0
```