# Pandas: how to normalize a column after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, normalization

I have a dataFrameGroupBy object with several columns, on of them is 'price'.

Since each group has a different price range, I would like to normalize each group separately.

following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046208/normalize-dataframe-by-group) I tried :

`grouped['priceNormed'] = grouped['price'].transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean()) / x.std())`

but I get an error `TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment`

The difference is (I think) that I am grouping by one column, but want to normalize another.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to change the groupby object. Instead, you'll have to make a new object that has the changes you want.

Comment: so to iterate group by group? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign back to the **DataFrame**, not GroupBy object:

```
grouped = df.groupby(...)
df['priceNormed'] = grouped['price'].transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean()) / x.std())
```